# Python 2.7 CSVファイルの日本語文字読み込み

Tags: python, python2

```
import csv

with open('datas.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

    for line in csv_reader:
        print(line)
```

これでファイルを入れていますが、コードをRUNしたら

```
'2018\x94N12\x8c\x8e30\x93\xfa(\x93\xfa)'
```

これは出ています。CSVファイルをENCODE方法がありますか？

Comment: CSVファイルをメモ帳(Windowsの場合)などのテキストエディタで開き、エンコードをutf-8(BOMなし）に変更してから保存してください。そうすればCSVファイルのエンコーディングがutf-8(BOMなし)に変わります。

Answer (score 1):

ファイルを[open](https://docs.python.jp/2.7/library/csv.html#examples)する時にエンコーディングを指定してください。
指定しない場合はOSシステムのデフォルトエンコーディングになって文字化けします。

```
import csv
import codecs

# encodingを指定して読み込み
with codecs.open('datas.csv', 'r', 'shift_jis') as csv_file:
# 3.x以降ならば下記の記述も可能
# with open('datas.csv', 'r', encoding="shift_jis") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    for line in csv_reader:
        print(line)
```

Comment: 有難う御座います。ですがこれのエラーが回ってきます。https://imgur.com/a/a73a4IT

Comment: 失礼しました。エンコーディングの指定が誤っていたので回答を修正しました。再度ご確認をお願いします。

Comment: 今は`'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-6: ordinal not in range(128)`と言う問題があります。これを避ける為　`errors="ignore"` を入れても解決できません。

Answer (score 1):

読んだ行をshift_jisからdecodeする方法です。

```py
import csv
import codecs

with open('datas.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    for line in csv_reader:
        line = [codecs.decode(s, 'shift_jis') for s in line] #読んだ行をshift_jisからデコード
        print(line)
        for s in line:
            print(s)
```